# Where x character equal value

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I select records where in the column `Value` the 5th character is letter A?

For example the following records:

```
ID            Value
-------------------------
 1             1234A5636A6363
 2             1234A4343B6363
 3             1234B5353A6363
```

if I run

```
select * from table
where Value like '%A%'
```

this will return all records

but all I want is the first 2 where the 5th character is A, regardless if there are more A characters in the text or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * 
from your_table
where substring(Value, 5, 1) = 'A'
```

Comment: Note that the performance of `LIKE` and substring are probably fairly similar here; only needing to walk down the first five characters of the string to make a decision +1.

Answer (score 3):

The `LIKE` operator, in addition to `%`, which matches any number of any character, can use `_`, which matches any one single character.  You may try:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE Value LIKE '____A%';  -- 4 underscores here
```

Comment: First answer given, completely correct, and yet it gets downvoted.

Comment: oh. we can't have that. :)

Comment: On the one hand, this is arguably the "right" way to do it, since its standards-complaint. On the other hand, using `SUBSTRING` might be more readable (how many underscores are there again?)

Answer (score 0):

use like below by using _(underscore)

```
LIKE '____A%'
```

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Server**

```
select *
from  YourTableName
where CHARINDEX('A', ColumnName) = 5
```

**Note:-** This finds where string 'A' starts at position 5
AND specify Your ColumnName